# Optional Argument in C#, reference other argument

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a recursive function in C# that will take two arguments, an Array, and an index.  The index should change on each recursion, but start being the length of the Array - 1.

Like this:

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num, int i = num.Length - 1) {...}
```

However, I cannot reference num. I could pass along a boolean stating whether this is the first time through or not and include an if-clause in the code.  But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: Personally, I would use `int[] num, int i = -1` and use the `-1` as a *magic number* to indicate that you should set `i` to `num.Length` inside the method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the default value for an optional parameter *has* to be a constant.

You could use `-1` as the default value as suggested in comments, or make it a nullable int and default it to null:

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num, int? index = null)
{
    int realIndex = index ?? num.Length - 1;
    ...
}
```

Or better yet, just have two methods:

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num)
{
    return UpArray(num, num.Length - 1);
}

private static int[] UpArray(int[] num, int index)
{
    ...
}
```

That's assuming you don't *want* the external caller to actually specify the index - you just want to do that on the recursive calls.

No need for any optional parameters, and the overall API is what you really want, rather than it letting implementation details peek through.

Comment: I personally like the "better yet."

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Me too - it was only after rereading the question and catching the "first time through" that it became clearer to me :)

Comment: @JonSkeet The *better yet* tends to be a more clean manner of implementing it, in my opinion. It also keeps the actual work from being exposed (and potentially abused).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an anonymous method:

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num) {
  Func<int[], int> f = null;
  f = (int[] num, int i) => {
    //Do something and then something like:
    f(num, num.Length - 1);
  };
  f(num, num.Length);
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the only method you are able to call is the outer one; the inner, anonymous, method isn't possible to call. It's clean and is not polluting the namespace. When you are about to call the method there is only one method, and no risk of invoking the wrong method (or just trying to figure out which method to call.)

Comment: It's clean code, and it's grouped neatly. No risk of code being separated in the file. It's short and easy to follow. No magic numbers. What's complicated?

Comment: Let's agree to disagree

Comment: I agree that you are entitled to an opinion, and I respect that, but I don't understand the down vote. I understand if you prefer, and up vote, another solution, but that alone shouldn't justify a down vote. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1):

It may be more elegant to use an overload which doesn't require an index. This will also allow the function to be used as a method group when needed in place of a lambda, since lambdas can't utilize the optional parameters' defaults

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num) { return UpArray(num, num.Length - 1); }
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num, int index)
{
    //...
}
```

this also allows you to hide the inner function if you want to force implementation to use always start at the end:

```
public static int[] UpArray(int[] num) //...
private static int[] UpArray(int[] num, int index) //...
```